# jQuery not stopping POST after executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4, and in one of my views I'm going to be using jQuery. The jQuery is written on the create page. It is as follows:

\View:

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h2>Strategy Types</h2></td>

            </tr>
        <tr class ="strategyType">
            @{
                int count = 0;
                List<LearningEnterprises.ViewModel.AssignedStrategyType> strategytypes = ViewBag.StrategyType;

                foreach (var strategytype in strategytypes)
                {
                    if (count++ % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        @:</tr><tr>
                    }
                    @:<td>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                           name="selectedStrategyTypes"
                           value="@strategytype.StrategyTypeID"
                            />
                           @strategytype.StrategyTypeID @:  @strategytype.Title
                    @:</td>
                }
                @:</tr>
            }
        <tr> 
        <td class="strategyTypeVal">

        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="createButton" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

\jQuery

```
<script>
    if ($(".strategyType td input:checked").length == 0 && $(".strategyTypeVal").empty()) {
        $(".strategyTypeVal").append("Please select at least one strategy type.").css("font-weight", "Bold").css('color', 'red');
    }
    else { $(".strategyTypeVal").empty(); }
```

Now the code displays the error message properly, but the post still goes through, it doesn't stop the website from creating an article.

Comment: Your if condition is not proper, `.empty()` will return a object every time so it will be always truthy. Try `if ($(".strategyType td input:checked").length == 0 && $.trim($(".strategyTypeVal").text()).length == 0) {
    $(".strategyTypeVal").append("Please select at least one strategy type.").css("font-weight", "Bold").css('color', 'red');
} else {
    $(".strategyTypeVal").empty();
}`

Comment: Also where are you trying to prevent the form submit

Comment: yeah. If no checkboxes are selected then the form doesn't submit